# Angular delete - API is not receiving the call

Tags: javascript, angular, asp.net-core-webapi

I have the following auto-generated code (NSwag Studio) - the only amendment is `withCredentials` which I've added for Windows Auth (intranet app).

```js
    deleteObjective(id: number): Observable<ObjectiveDTO> {
        let url_ = this.baseUrl + "/api/Objectives/{id}";
        if (id === undefined || id === null)
            throw new Error("The parameter 'id' must be defined.");
        url_ = url_.replace("{id}", encodeURIComponent("" + id)); 
        url_ = url_.replace(/[?&]$/, "");

        let options_ : any = {
            observe: "response",
            responseType: "blob",
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                "Accept": "application/json"
            })
        };

        return this.http.request("delete", url_, options_).pipe(_observableMergeMap((response_ : any) => {
            return this.processDeleteObjective(response_);
        })).pipe(_observableCatch((response_: any) => {
            if (response_ instanceof HttpResponseBase) {
                try {
                    return this.processDeleteObjective(<any>response_);
                } catch (e) {
                    return <Observable<ObjectiveDTO>><any>_observableThrow(e);
                }
            } else
                return <Observable<ObjectiveDTO>><any>_observableThrow(response_);
        }));
    }
```

everything else in the generated service works fine (this is the only delete) but this is literally not sending any traffic - in the Chrome Network pullout (F12) there is no call to the API and the API does not receive anything.

I am calling it from my component like this:

```js
  deleteObjective(): void {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this objective? This cannot be un-done.')) {
      if (this.objective.id !== 0)
        this.service.deleteObjective(this.objective.id);

      for (var i = 0; i < this.objectives.length; i++) {
        if (this.objectives[i] === this.objective) {
          this.objectives.splice(i, 1);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

and the splice is definitely working. If I put `debugger` before the http request it calls it. There are no errors in the console.

Any ideas? I am new to angular but old to programming.

Comment: You have to subscribe to the object returned by the deleteObjective function.

Comment: Ahhh! Thanks! That makes so much sense.

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling the function from the service, make sure you `subscribe()` to it.

Answer (score 0):

The API will be hit only after you **subscribe**

Try like this:

```
  deleteObjective(): void {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this objective? This cannot be un-done.')) {
      if (this.objective.id !== 0)
        this.service.deleteObjective(this.objective.id).subscribe(res => {
          for (var i = 0; i < this.objectives.length; i++) {
            if (this.objectives[i] === this.objective) {
              this.objectives.splice(i, 1);
            }
          }
        })
    }
  }
```